# Is it possible to convert a file to a raw string in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

In kotlin theres raw strings, made with `"""` and escaped strings made with `"`, I was wondering if there is a way to read a file as a raw string.

I'm using `java.io.File` like so `File("path").readText()` to parse files usually, but now I need to get the raw string, which I don't think `.readText()` gives.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "raw string"? 2) What is the contents of the file? 3) What are you trying to do with the file?

Comment: 1) By raw string I mean a string which contains escape codes such as \n in plain text
2) A raw string, including escape codes(`\", \n etc`)
3) Count the number of characters in a raw string

Comment: Should `\n` be counted as one character, two characters, or zero characters?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip 2 characters, will read up on that.

Comment: OK. Then it depends if the file contains an actual newline, or if it contains the \ and `n` characters. It also depends on the character encoding of the file!

Comment: It contains the characters \ and `n` and its UTF-8

Comment: OK, I updated the answer. I think your `readText()` should work, you just need to use `length` to count the number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't make sense, because the `"` and `"""` tokens are only used when parsing the source file. Once the value is assigned to a variable, it's a string. There is no need to convert between one or the other.

```
fun main() {
    val singleQuoted = "foo\nbar"
    val trippleQuoted = """
        foo
        bar
    """.trimIndent()
    check(singleQuoted == trippleQuoted)
}
```

Here you can see the two strings are the same, even though they were created with different syntax.

---

In response to edited question:

The number of characters in a file depends on the character encoding of the file. Check out [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

To count the number of `bytes` in a file, which will equal the number of characters if the file is ASCII, you can do:

```
File("path").length()
```

If the file is UTF-8, you can count the number of characters like this:

```
File("path").readText().length
```

If it's another file encoding, you can pass the encoding to `readText()`:

```
File("path").readText(Charset.forName("UTF-16")).length
```

Comment: I've edited the question to add more clarification.